# See if number a is closer to c than b

Tags: php, function, math, integer

I am currently trying to make a function that can tell if number `a` is closer to `c` than the number `b` is to `c`.

I have tried to do comparisons like so: (taking `a` and `b` from `c` and comparing those)

```
$c = 10;
$b = 2;
$a = 3;

$b_check = $c - $b; // = 8.
$a_check = $c - $a; // = 7.
```

In my head, I thought that whatever number (`a` or `b`) is smaller means that it's gonna be the closer number to `c`, though that worked using positive integers, but when it came to negative integers it gave the complete wrong outcome.

I was wondering if maybe there was an `in-built function` in `PHP` for this or if there's a better mathematical method for achieving this?

Comment: Look at [abs()](http://php.net/abs)

Comment: You may want to check if each number is positive or negative before doing your math in order to perform the correct equation.  @jszobody, I was thinking the same thing with `abs()`, but if `c` is positive and `b` is negative `abs()` is going to lead to a wrong outcome.

Comment: @SgtAJ just depends on how you use it =)

Comment: (abs($c-$a)>abs($c-$b))? $b:$a;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If (a - c) * (a - c) < (b - c) * (b - c)` would do it. This gets round the negative number issue and is the way us old cats do it in C.

Else you could use `Math.abs(a - c) < Math.abs(b - c)` but the other way *can* be quicker for some types, but you need to take care not to *overflow* your type and there's a potential for a ruinous *wraparound* effect for some types too.

Profile it.

Comment: `way us old cats do it in C` Instantly my favourite answer of all time :)

Comment: Ha. You have to be careful in C though not to overflow your type. The behaviour on doing that is undefined for some types, and the compiler reserves the right to eat your cat.

Comment: I get what you mean with all that :) And hey just a quick question before I tick and you go off, would it be more effective to just do a `pow` (power) like so - `pow(a - c) < pow(b - c)`?

Comment: You need an even power greater than 0 to cancel a negative sign. But I dislike using `pow` to square a number even if good compilers make a claim that they optimise it out: `pow(x, y)` is often implemented in C as exp (y * log(x)) and that obviously can introduce imprecision. But I'm being naughty here, as this question is tagged php!

Comment: Ahaha its all good! Be as naughty as ya want ;) Anyway thanks for answer added it to my code and it works amazing! Really appreciated :)

Comment: @eggyal: U wot? Counterexample: a = -1, b = 10, c = 0.

Comment: Apologies, my maths failed me momentarily: you can rearrange to get `(a + b)(a - b) < 2c(a - b)` and I then tried to cancel the `(a - b)` factors (stipulating a!=b) but forgot that it would cause the inequality to be negated when b>a.

Comment: We'll publish jointly!

Answer (score 1):

The one with the smallest absolute value is always the closest.  You're thinking in terms of a number line, but it's easier to imagine if you know vectors in 2D or 3D space.  Then the distance between two points is the square root of the sum of squares of the difference between their components.  The 1D case falls out as a special case where two components are zero.

```
double distance = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)) = Math.abs(x2-x1)
```

Comment: Obviously though there's no need to compute the square root as it's a transformation that preserves order.

Comment: I think it should be clear: no need to calculate the square root for the 1D case; I spelled out the absolute value.  I did it that way because it explains how this fits into 3D vectors.